# Error while using Whisper-1 API for audio transcription in SpringBoot webapplication

Tags: java, spring-boot, audio, inputstream, openai-api

CONTROLLER CLASS

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bot")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class SttController {

    @Autowired
    SttService service;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/transcribeAudio", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Flux<SttResponse> transcription(@ModelAttribute SttRequest sttRequest){
        return service.transcribeAudio(sttRequest);
    }
}
```

SERVICE LAYER

```
@Service
public class SttService {

    @Value("${openai.api.model}")
    private String model;
    
    @Value("${openai.api.url}")
    private String apiURL;
    
    WebClient builder = WebClient.create();
    
    public Flux<SttResponse> transcribeAudio(SttRequest sttRequest){
        SttRequest audioRequest = SttRequest.builder()
                  .model(model)
                  .file(sttRequest.getFile())
                  .build();
        return builder.post().uri(apiURL).bodyValue(audioRequest).retrieve().bodyToFlux(SttResponse.class);
    }
}
```

```
2023-07-23T19:55:28.513+05:30 ERROR 215000 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream]] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.stt.dto.SttRequest["file"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1308) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:30) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:479) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:318) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1572) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1061) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:252) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.lambda$encode$0(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:158) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.doOnRequest(MonoSingle.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.request(Operators.java:2878) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoSingle.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:445) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:710) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:195) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:456) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelActive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:62) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:238) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelActive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:69) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:211) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:260) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:238) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler.userEventTriggered(SslProvider.java:856) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:400) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:376) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:368) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeSuccess(SslHandler.java:1848) ~[netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:952) ~[netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1419) ~[netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1246) ~[netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295) ~[netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I am trying to use openAI's whisper-1 API to transcribe audio to text using springboot. I am using webflux to hit the whisper-1 API's endpoint, which I specified in the application properties.  But I am getting this error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.stt.dto.SttRequest["file"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"])